# Unable to compile boost with Python 2.7

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, python-2.7, boost

I have a code project that uses the C++ Boost library in order to build Voronoi cells. I have pasted the boost header under a directory called boost and my C++ code refers to it. However, compiling the code does not work and return the following errors. When my code was simply depending on the polygon package, compiling was working fine. The compilation started to fail when I started importing the bimap package.

I am using Windows 7, Python 2.7, and Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7. I know that if I try to compile boost separately on windows using this compiler it fails as well (whereas I have always been able to compile with Visual Studio Compiler 11). **Does anyone know what is causing this issue?**

Below are the pre-processing instructions for the piece of code using boost, and then the error message returned at compile time:

Pre-processor instructions:

```
#define BOOST_POLYGON_NO_DEPS
#define BOOST_NO_USER_CONFIG
#define BOOST_NO_COMPILER_CONFIG
#define BOOST_NO_STDLIB_CONFIG
#define BOOST_NO_PLATFORM_CONFIG
#define BOOST_HAS_STDINT_H
#define __GLIBC__
```

Here are error message returned by the compiler:

```
Development mode: Compiling Cython modules from .pyx sources.
running build_ext
skipping 'pyvoronoi\pyvoronoi.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pyvoronoi' extension
C:\Users\fancelin\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ipyvoronoi -IC:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\include -IC:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\PC /Tppyvoronoi\pyvoronoi.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pyvoronoi\pyvoronoi.obj /EHsc
pyvoronoi.cpp
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'user-defined conversion'
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(30) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mpl_::bool_<C_>' being compiled
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'user-defined conversion'
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/na.hpp(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mpl_::bool_<C_>' being compiled
        with
        [
            C_=false
        ]
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/na.hpp(31) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::is_na<T>' being compiled
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'user-defined conversion'
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/na.hpp(36) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mpl_::bool_<C_>' being compiled
        with
        [
            C_=true
        ]
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/bool.hpp(29) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(80) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'user-defined conversion'
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mpl_::integral_c<T,N>' being compiled
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(80) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(80) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'user-defined conversion'
        pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(81) : see reference to class template instantiation 'mpl_::int_<N>' being compiled
pyvoronoi\boost/mpl/aux_/integral_wrapper.hpp(80) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(76) : error C2065: 'char16_t' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(76) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(76) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(76) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(76) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(79) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(79) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(79) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp(79) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'boost::is_integral' is not a specialization of a class template
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_rvalue_reference.hpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&&'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_rvalue_reference.hpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_rvalue_reference.hpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(14) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(19) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/yes_no_type.hpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(14) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(15) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(22) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(28) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(28) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(32) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_and.hpp(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(13) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(14) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(18) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(26) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(28) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_not.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(13) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(14) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(18) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(26) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(29) : error C2065: 'b2' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(29) : error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(29) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(30) : error C2065: 'b2' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(30) : error C2039: 'value' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(30) : error C2065: 'value' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/ice_eq.hpp(34) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(34) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(36) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(38) : error C2039: 'is_reference_impl' : is not a member of 'boost::detail'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(38) : error C2065: 'is_reference_impl' : undeclared identifier
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(38) : error C2975: 'val' : invalid template argument for 'boost::integral_constant', expected compile-time constant expression
        pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/integral_constant.hpp(18) : see declaration of 'val'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(38) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_reference.hpp(40) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(19) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(32) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(37) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(45) : error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(48) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(51) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(53) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(54) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(55) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(58) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(60) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(60) : error C2039: 'add_reference_impl' : is not a member of 'boost::detail'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(60) : error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/add_reference.hpp(68) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(32) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(33) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(34) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(35) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(37) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(38) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(39) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(40) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(22) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(23) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(101) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(105) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(109) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
pyvoronoi\boost/type_traits/detail/cv_traits_impl.hpp(109) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Boost, but a syntax error in a header file (the very first error) is often cause by an error in the line before the `#include`.

Comment: I see. So the issue may lie with the pre-processing instructions the program is given then. I will edit the question to include that. Thanks.